# How to show how-much data is needed to download while apt-get?

Tags: command-line, apt

I want to know how-much data is needed to download any package by `apt` without installing that package.

In other words if I run `apt-get install xyz` then it will download and install packages with their dependencies. But I want to know/show **only** how-much (Total)data (ex:`need to get 73MB of archives`) to download **without downloading and installing** that package(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it could be possible through parsing `apt-get` command. Try the below command to show how much disk space will be used for installing that package,

```
echo 'n' | sudo apt-get install package | sed -n '/^After/ s/^[^,]*, \(.*\)$/\1/p'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'n' | sudo apt-get install chromium-browser | sed -n '/^After/ s/^[^,]*, \(.*\)$/\1/p'
176 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

**OR**

Try the below command to show the size of archives needed to be downloaded for that particular package.

```
echo 'n' | sudo apt-get install package | sed -n '/^Need to get/p'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'n' | sudo apt-get install chromium-browser | sed -n '/^Need to get/p'
Need to get 44.4 MB of archives.
```

Comment: grep? no need for that.

Comment: Thank-you. `echo n | sudo apt-get install package` works fine I use `echo n | sudo apt-get install package | grep "Need to get"`

Comment: It works also. And what about this `echo n | sudo apt-get install boswars | awk '/^Need to get/'`?

Comment: Same result. In fact `echo n | sudo apt-get install package` is important then we use sed/awk/grep whatever. I like `grep` because it is simple to use.

Comment: Yep. That's your wish.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DevGeek's contribution, another forum post similar to yours answered by enzotib rounded out the question fairly succinctly:
[How to determine the size of a package while using apt prior to downloading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35956/how-to-determine-the-size-of-a-package-in-terminal-prior-to-downloading)

Specifically,

apt-cache --no-all-versions show $package | grep '^Size: '

Hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Usually apt-get will ask for a confirmation before downloading archives. For example, if I type

```
sudo apt-get install googlecl
```

apt-get will print

```
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
Need to get 547 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,551 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

As you see, for installing googlecl (on my computer) it will download 547kB. To cancel the download, simply type 'n' and presss enter.

Comment: It not always ask for conformation.

Comment: Oops, you are right! Please refer to Avinash Raj's or SonOfEntropy's answer.